# Can I set font-size relative to page size?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to make `font-size` relative to the size of the page? Applying percentage as unit refers to the standard font size (like 90% of 12px, not 90% of the page!). This is different from the behaviour of most of the other tags.

Any way to make the page 'scale up and down' also with fonts? Should I rely on `em`?

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No you cannot set the size of the font in a percentage relative to the size of the page.

Sizing in `em` is based on the size relative to how the font would normally render in 16 point.

If you'd like your page to scale up and down and keep some sort of scale to itself, the boxes and the font, then setting it out in `em` would be fine.

That method will allow for the scaling of fonts and boxes of the page to grow at a relative size to one another and hopefully not have things falling out of bounds and borders.

Comment: It should be worth noting that it's relative to the browser's default font size, which may or may not be 16 points (Albeit, this is the default on desktop browsers).

Comment: That is true, 16pt for the default size on browsers. And you really can't guess at hand if the user has it set larger or smaller which might be a bit of a bother if the CSS is dependent on that.

Comment: so I said <font size=10em>foo</font> and I expected "foo"'s size to scale with the browser window. That did not happen.

Comment: had to adapt an app for extra large screens, you just saved my life <3

Comment: Maybe things changed since the time this answer was written, but today the EdF+Ninjacannon solution is by far more useful (and in fact helped me a lot)

Answer (score 37):

See the new vh and vw CSS units.  Browser support isn't great yet.

http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/vm-vh-units

It landed in WebKit recently:
https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=27160

In browsers that support it, `1 vh` is 1% (1/100) of the viewport height, and `1 vw` is 1% (1/100) of the viewport width.  There are also `vmin` and `vmax` units, which represent the smaller of the two and the larger of the two, respectively.

Comment: You should clarify that this isn't as yet widely supported and that it came in CSS3. And perhaps more on what the vh and vm instead of a naked link to a blog

Comment: "Browser support isn't great yet."Also, this is the Internet, no? Why should I rehash what's already been written? We should reward good sources of info with traffic, not try to silo it away.

Comment: That's a fine proposition if linkrot was never a thing http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: Interesting read, thanks for sharing it. If you'd like to edit my answer (is that a thing here?) feel free to do so aka "pull requests welcome"

Comment: cool, here is an example how to do it: <font style="font-size:5vh">this is a test</font>

Comment: Thirsten Staerk: the font element died with HTML4 and as was mentioned, vw and vh are not supported by all browsers.Your comment is bad advise on two counts.

Answer (score 9):

Try a jQuery plugin like [FitText](http://fittextjs.com/). It automatically sizes text to fit the width of the parent element.

Another jQuery plugin with the same goal is [BigText](http://www.zachleat.com/web/bigtext-makes-text-big/) ([demo](http://www.zachleat.com/bigtext/demo/)).

Answer (score 4):

In my view, the range of apparent pixel densities seen by the viewer of a webpage is now massive, from an HTC One held at 12 inches from the face, where there are 5600 pixels/radians to perhaps a 50 inch plasma screen running at 480p, which is about 950 pixels/radians at 4 feet.

Or put it another way a 20px font is nearly 6x bigger in your field of view on that plasma screen than the latest handset.

The solution I cooked up was to set the body font size in absolute pixels as a multiple of the `window.screenWidth` but constrain it to a minimum an maximum number of units, then use em's for all font sizes after that. The em's+proper use of headings should mean accessibility is fine.

I add this function to the page (or it's JS) to set the size:

```
function setFontSize() {
    pagesized = window.innerWidth / 30; // Proportionate font size to page
    pagesized = Math.max(pagesized, 14); // Set size to be no less than 14 px
    pagesized = Math.min(pagesized, 30); // & No greater than 30 px
    document.body.style.fontSize = pagesized; // Set body default font size
}
```

To make this work the following is added to the body tag:

```
<body onresize="setFontSize()" onload="setFontSize()">
```

You then just use your CSS (or inline formatting) all based on % or em units and things should scale nicely within those bounds.

Or, in JQuery, you can do:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    pagesized = $(window).innerWidth() / 30; // Proportionate font size to page
    pagesized = Math.max(pagesized, 14); // Set size to be no less than 14 px
    pagesized = Math.min(pagesized, 30); // & No greater than 30 px
    $('body').css('font-size', pagesized); // Set body default font size
});
```

Comment: This solution worked for me with a minor fix: just add the unit to the last statement in the "setFontSize" function (...pagesized+"px";). Next, you set other font sizes in em (1em if equal to the fontsize of the body). Simple and effective.

Answer (score 4):

Another non-ideal answer is to use a series of css breakpoints like so:

```
h1 { font-size: 22px; color: orange; }
@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  h1 { font-size: 20px; color: blue; }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  h1 { font-size: 18px; color: green; }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  h1 { font-size: 12px; color: red; }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8RKhp/

Answer (score 3):

Heres a little script I made for exacly that (use it as a fallback when vw isnt supported)
https://gist.github.com/2475269

Answer (score 2):

At least for Firefox, `1em` can be used to set the font size related to the font size of the parent. So if you set font-size of body to a value that is in ratio to the size of the page. All fonts under body that use 'em' as unit will be in relation to the page.

To do that, you must set the size of the body in relation to the page like `height: 100%` or width if you want to relate the size to the width.

Then, you will have to constantly synchronize the body height with the font size. This can be done with 'onResize'.

See more detail in the following [link](http://blog.nawaman.net/2010/01/cssjavascript-technique-for-setting-font-size-based-on-the-page-size/#respond).

Comment: the link does not exist any more on jul 31th 2012

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use [YUI reset](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/) to unify the font rendering across different browsers. Then check [YUI Font Size](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/fonts/fonts-size.html). After this you can rely on your fonts to display correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

// Dynamisches Skalieren von Schriften
fontSize = function(){
//ww = $(window).innerWidth();
ww = $('.mainhead').innerWidth(); // Width of the Motherelement
one = ww/100; // 1%
multiplcator = one*31; 
$('.mainhead').css({'font-size': multiplcator+'px'});
}
fontSize();



$(window).resize(function() {
fontSize();
});

});
```

When you now set your Fontsize via css it wokes on all browsers like charm

```
.mainhead{
width:48%;
font: normal 2em Times, Verdana, sans-serif;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's already been answered, but i need to share this for future `comers`, because it took me some precious minutes to figure this out.

So as mr @random said: `em` as a unit,  will do the trick.

> If you'd like your page to scale up and down and keep some sort of scale to itself, the boxes and the font, then setting it out in em would be fine.

That method will allow for the scaling of fonts and boxes of the page to grow at a relative size to one another and hopefully not have things falling out of bounds and borders.

Initialise your `body` with `1em` as `font-size` that means `100%`

```
body {
      font-size: 1em; 
}
```

Then set your element's `font-size` as a percentage of it's parent's

```
.your_element {
 font-size:0.4em /* for example 40% if its parent font-size */
}
```

Now the `magic` of `@media` queries

```
@media all and (max-width: 767px) {
  body {
    font-size: 0.4em !important;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1023px) {
  body {
    font-size: 0.6em !important;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
  body {
    font-size: 0.8em !important;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width: 1200px) and (max-width: 1599px) {
  body {
    font-size: 1em !important;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width: 1600px) and (max-width: 1999px) {
  body {
    font-size: 1.2em !important;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width: 2000px) and (max-width: 2999px) {
  body {
    font-size: 1.6em !important;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width: 3000px) and (max-width: 3999px) {
  body {
    font-size: 1.8em !important;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width: 4000px) {
  body {
    font-size: 2em !important;
  }
}
```

And Bingo, have a nice day.

Answer (score -3):

When you say "relative to the size of the page", what exactly do you mean with "size of the page"?

The browser window? Then your fonts would change size when the user resizes the window - definitely not what anyone would expect, and pretty bad for usability. People don't resize windows to see a larger or smaller representation of the whole site, they enlarge them to see a larger *section* of the site, and make windows smaller to see a specific small section and have space for other windows next to the browser.

If you mean the size of the screen, that's even worse since it would mean huge fonts on a 30" screen. But people don't buy 30" screens so they can see huge fonts, they buy them to see multiple windows side by side.

All in all, using em or something similay is the only sensible way to make a scaleable website, since it will scale relative to the default size, which is/should be relative to what the user can comfortably read.

Comment: hi, i'm aware of the usability problem, but this is exacly what I do need. it is a page for a couple of very large displays.

Comment: Very large but differently-sized? Can't you just use Firefox and its zoom feature on those displays then? Alternatively, have the page scale using em and configure each display to use an appropriate default font size.

Comment: `definitely not what anyone would expect` actually this may be exactly what the user expects, for example in a game where all of the graphics and text grows proportionally to the size of the window.

Comment: It's a perfectly reasonable ask when developing something for mobile, as long as you keep fonts from getting too small.