# Responsive font-size/weight

Tags: html, css

I can make my images/divs responsive by using percentages.

How can I make the font-size responsive to different screen sizes?

Comment: You might be interested in [this][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181689/font-size-relative-to-page-size

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to increase font size based on window width?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146395/how-to-increase-font-size-based-on-window-width)

Comment: I'd ask "should I?". Often browser resizing is to see more content--not bigger content. We have browser zoom to deal with the latter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I stumbled across this problem recently and I wrote a solution for it that suits my needs. Maybe you will find that you can incorporate it into your CSS as well.

[github.com/wadim/responsive-font-size](http://github.com/wadim/responsive-font-size)

Usage:

```
@import "responsive-font-size";

p {
    @include responsive-font-size (
        $min-font-size: 1.8em,
        $max-font-size: 3.7em,
        $min-screen-width: 640px,
        $max-screen-width: 1200px,
        $font-size-step: 0.3em /* optional parameter, default: 0.1em */
    );
}
```

It basically says:

- for screen width smaller than 640px I want the font-size to be 1.8em
- for screen width greater than 1200px I want it to be 3.7em
- scale the font appropriately in between
- don't bother changing the font size by less than 0.3em

Answer (score 3):

If you want it to change when you hit width milestones (e.g. 768px, 370px, etc.), then use a CSS3 media query. If you want it to be constantly changing, then you could use the same percentage, or em, technique as with the images/divs (i.e. target / context = result), but I would suggest media queries.

Answer (score 3):

You can use  CSS3  `vh`, `vw`,`vmin` and `vmax` new values for responsive font.

[image]

1vw = 1% of viewport width

1vh = 1% of viewport height

1vmin = 1vw or 1vh, whichever is smaller

1vmax = 1vw or 1vh, whichever is larger

```
h1 {
font-size: 5.9vw;
}
h2 {
font-size: 3.0vh;
}
p {
font-size: 2vmin;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the array of browsers you have to support, CSS3 Viewport-percentage lengths might be a good solution:

http://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/

http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-values/#viewport-relative-lengths

I decided against this approach since it is only supported on iOS6 and not Android, and my project is a tablet & smartphone mobile site.