# Is it possible to make the text fit to the biggest size but still keep in one single line?

Tags: html, css

I have a `#container`, it can be very wide or very narrow according to the screen size. I want the text (it can be any string, like a letter, a word or some words) inside it to expand to its biggest size but keep in one line. Is it possible to get this effect via pure CSS? If it needs other stuff (like JavaScript), how do I make this happen?

update:

though the container's width change as the screen size changes, it is a fixed number defined by @media query. For example, when the screen size is very big, say bigger than 1000px, the div won't expand but stay at a fixed width. If I use the `vw` type, it's still expanding and can break into two lines. So what I want the `font-size` to follow is the div's width, not the screen's. If the div expands/shrinks, it changes. If the div is fixed, no matter how big is the screen, it stays.

Thanks,

I've made a image to describe what I expect:

[image]

Comment: look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181689/font-size-relative-to-page-size

Comment: Use `display: table; white-space: nowrap;`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `vw` unit for your purpose. I have used `4vw` which means **4% of viewport width**. You can change it to your comfortable unit.

```css
.text-box {
  font-size: 4vw;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  width: auto;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="text-box">I am a single line, I expand and contract as well</div>
</div>
```

View it on [**JSfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Manojkr/61199L8t/2/embedded/result/)